# Why every reference book gives the formula for the integral $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$ as $\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometric-integrals

> > Why every reference book gives the formula for the integral as: $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} =\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$$

The reason why I am asking this is, for example by the above formula we have $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}}=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+C$$

But on the other hand, we have $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(-2)^2-x^2}}=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{-2}\right)+C=-\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+C$$

So according to me the following formula removes the above ambiguity:
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} =\frac{|a|}{a} \times \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$$

Any comments?

Comment: Try differentiating the one with the negative sign, and discover you do not get the original integrand. Then stop pretending you have checked **all** reference books **everywhere**.  Finally, discover that good reference books restrict $a$ to positive values to begin with.

Comment: Indeed the formula is valid for $a > 0$. If the textbook does not explicitly mention this condition, I guess it is due to either a mistake or sloppiness. I believe any decent calculus textbook explicitly mentions this condition, for example, as in the [OpenStax Calculus Textbook](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/a-table-of-integrals).

Comment: It is implied that $a$ is positive in the first formula. If your references aren’t making that clear, they should be.

Comment: Yes I should not have mentioned every reference book. Thanks

Comment: Also, your profile has a grammatical error/typo in its second sentence.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Do you mean there is a typo in my MSE profile?

Comment: Yes. *It's* easy to discover *its* location.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this back to first principles. Setting $x=a\sin\phi$ where $a$ could be negative, we get
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int\frac{a\cos\phi\,d\phi}{|a\cos\phi|}.
$$
If the domain of the substitution is fixed to $[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$, then the cosine is positive and indeed the sign of $a$ occurs as factor
$$
={\rm sign}(a)\phi+C={\rm sign}(a)\arcsin\left(\frac xa\right)+C=\arcsin\left(\frac x{|a|}\right)+C
$$
So the result is independent of the sign of $a$, as it should be, as the original integral is also independent of that sign. Thus it is no restriction to chose $a>0$ from the start.